# Which Complex Analysis book will be the best for a first reader?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Can anyone suggest me a good book of complex analysis? I only know the algebra of complex numbers.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ahlfors is the standard reference, and I have also heard good things about Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham.  I haven't read much of either though, so take these recommendations with a grain of salt.

Comment: I recommend the text: Stewart & Tall -- Complex Analysis (1983). It's out of print, but a used (very good) copy is available on Amazon for about $9$.

Comment: Do you have a good background in real analysis and Fourier analysis ?

Comment: Will you be reading this on your own, or with an instructor?

Comment: I would recommend this video course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/complex-analysis

Comment: Try "Functions of One Complex Variable" by John B. Conway.

Comment: I will be reading on my own.. And I know basic real analysis and metric spaces.. @GEdgar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I researched many complex analysis texts for a seminar and I have to say the following: For a first-time reader, both Ahlfors and Stein-Shakarchi would be too much (except if you are a graduate student and have a good feeling of analysis). Also, Stein's book has a strange sense of "proving" for the theorems (in general, that 4 books of Stein are written in a flowing style aiming for graduate students who want to proceed fast), and also there are some things about the structure of that book (the winding number is defined very late, the Jordan curves are not defined at all and the undefined term "toy curve" is used instead). I liked these books but I don't recommend them to beginners.

You can go along the [Bak-Newman book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441972870) or [Brown-Churchill](http://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Brown-Churchill-Complex%20Variables%20and%20Application%208th%20edition.pdf) (which surprisingly is available for free(?)) and has a [solution manual](http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/~yasuda/ippansug/CVA-sol-7.pdf). The latter book is more intended for physics-mechanics students so many topological aspects are omitted from the text. Also [Needham's book](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m7034/book/VisualComplexAnalysis-Needham.pdf) is terrific, the only problem being its huge size. The last text is [An introduction to complex analysis](https://nnquan.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/giao-trinh-ham-phuc.pdf) by Kanishka Perera, Ravi Agarwal, and Sandra Pinelas which is a well-organized readable text with solutions included, aiming for students beginning complex analysis.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of Complex Functions* because it has lots of examples and many illuminating historical remarks. And, if you enjoy it, you can always read later *Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory*, by the same author.

Comment: Excellent choice! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you've already taken all your Calculus sequence (preferably taken Real Analysis, but Calculus may be enough here) and are familiar with line integrals, partials, multiple integrals, etc. then I can highly vouch for [*Complex Analysis (Princeton Lectures in Analysis, No. 2)* by Stein and Shakarchi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113858). I don't recommend this as being your first proof-based mathematics course though. [Here's](http://press.princeton.edu/TOCs/c7563.html) the table of contents.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/solutionsCA.pdf) is an online solution manual to the book someone has made. I recommend skimming through it to get an understanding of the kind of problems you'll be required to solve in this book.

Comment: Your last two links both named "Here" have, sadly, died.